# Trying to identify files with matching text from a list of text files with Python 3

Tags: python, windows, text

Trying to get this to work, I need to search dozens if not hundreds of plain text files for a matching string.  Right now just trying to get it to match the string and give usable output will work on searching multiple files next.

Python code:

```
mylines = []
with open ("M:\Tivo Movies\Cape Fear  (1962) .ts.txt", 'rt') as myfile:
for myline in myfile: 
    mylines.append(myline.rstrip('\n'))
index = 0
index = 0
prev = 0
str = mylines[0]
substr = "TCMHD"
while index < len(str):
str = mylines[0]
substr = "TCMHD"
while index < len(str):
  index = str.find(substr, index)
  if index == -1:
    break
  print(" " * (index - prev) + "TCMHD", end='')
  prev = index + len(substr)
  index += len(substr)
 print('\n' + str);
```

Text in file (contains "TCMHD" string):

title : Cape Fear
seriesTitle : Cape Fear
description : After being released from prison, an ex-con seeks revenge on the prosecutor who put him away, which includes making unsavory threats towards his wife and 12-year-old daughter. In time, the lawyer decides to fight back.
time : 2020-05-16T02:00:00Z
movieYear : 1962
isEpisode : false
iso_duration : PT2H56S
isEpisodic : false
showingBits : 4096
starRating : x5
tvRating : x5
displayMajorNumber : 238
callsign : TCMHD                <-------
seriesId : MV0000353349
programId : MV0000353349-0000353350
vActor : Mitchum|Robert
vActor : Peck|Gregory

Output from script:

C:\Users\Torvald>python C:\Users\Torvald\Desktop\TCM.py

title : Cape Fear

Comment: what's the problem you're facing in this?

Comment: it is returning all files even ones without the required tag string. and not including the TMCHD tag in the output list.